# Packet receiving thread doesn't work sometimes

Tags: android, android-service

Here is a brief description.

The Android service has a thread receiving a packet from a server. It is called as 'receiver'.
It is waiting for a packet with `inputStream.read()`.

Problem scenario is like this :

1. Server sends some request packet.
2. Receiver thread must wake up and process the packet, but doesn't work and print log.
3. Server closes a connection.
4. So, other thread of client closes a connection.
5. Receiver is terminated with 'ECONNRESET' suddenly.

Usually it works well. The problem occurs once a few hours as I think.

I guess it can be caused by some overload or sleep state of phone.
But I cannot decide which is clear.

The solution that I have came up with is currently like this :

1. Increase receiver thread priority.
2. Use wake lock and wifi lock.

I didn't try them yet because it is related with my business customer. Could you provide your opinion for this issue?

Comment: If you haven't yet, Can you try adding your network thread in the service.

Comment: @Milanix Sorry, what does mean 'adding'?